# Server side html filtering library in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE. I need server side Html input filtering function or library.
TinyMCE recommended

- [htmlLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/)
- [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)
- [Zend Filter Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html)

All of this only compatible with PHP. But i'm using `asp.net MVC`

Please tell me, is there any available filtering `library` or `attribute` in asp.net MVC

For example like this

```
[HtmlInputFilter] //<<--
public ActionResult Post(string html){
...
}
```

Comment: I've used [Microsoft AntiXSS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589) in the past which includes HTML sanitization. It uses a whitelist approach (any solution you select should do so). From looking at the source code, I feel their URL checks are a bit simplistic; also (last I checked) there was zero customization available. For example, maybe you don't want any images or links, sanitized or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Microsoft AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library to sanitize the HTML.

If you want to handle your own whitelists of tags and attributes the AntiXSS library is not suitable as it doesn't provide you with the necessary customization hooks. One possibility is to roll your own sanitizer (at your own risk of course). For example you could use the [`HTML Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for that. Here's a [`blog post`](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/whitelist-santize-htmlagilitypack/) illustrating a sample sanitizer:

```
public static class HtmlUtility
{
    // Original list courtesy of Robert Beal :
    // http://www.robertbeal.com/37/sanitising-html

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> ValidHtmlTags =
        new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            {"p", new string[]          {"style", "class", "align"}},
            {"div", new string[]        {"style", "class", "align"}},
            {"span", new string[]       {"style", "class"}},
            {"br", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"hr", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"label", new string[]      {"style", "class"}},

            {"h1", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"h2", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"h3", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"h4", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"h5", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"h6", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},

            {"font", new string[]       {"style", "class", "color", "face", "size"}},
            {"strong", new string[]     {"style", "class"}},
            {"b", new string[]          {"style", "class"}},
            {"em", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"i", new string[]          {"style", "class"}},
            {"u", new string[]          {"style", "class"}},
            {"strike", new string[]     {"style", "class"}},
            {"ol", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"ul", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"li", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"blockquote", new string[] {"style", "class"}},
            {"code", new string[]       {"style", "class"}},

            {"a", new string[]          {"style", "class", "href", "title"}},
            {"img", new string[]        {"style", "class", "src", "height", "width",
                "alt", "title", "hspace", "vspace", "border"}},

            {"table", new string[]      {"style", "class"}},
            {"thead", new string[]      {"style", "class"}},
            {"tbody", new string[]      {"style", "class"}},
            {"tfoot", new string[]      {"style", "class"}},
            {"th", new string[]         {"style", "class", "scope"}},
            {"tr", new string[]         {"style", "class"}},
            {"td", new string[]         {"style", "class", "colspan"}},

            {"q", new string[]          {"style", "class", "cite"}},
            {"cite", new string[]       {"style", "class"}},
            {"abbr", new string[]       {"style", "class"}},
            {"acronym", new string[]    {"style", "class"}},
            {"del", new string[]        {"style", "class"}},
            {"ins", new string[]        {"style", "class"}}
        };

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes raw HTML input and cleans against a whitelist
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Html source</param>
    /// <returns>Clean output</returns>
    public static string SanitizeHtml(string source)
    {
        HtmlDocument html = GetHtml(source);
        if (html == null) return String.Empty;

        // All the nodes
        HtmlNode allNodes = html.DocumentNode;

        // Select whitelist tag names
        string[] whitelist = (from kv in ValidHtmlTags
                              select kv.Key).ToArray();

        // Scrub tags not in whitelist
        CleanNodes(allNodes, whitelist);

        // Filter the attributes of the remaining
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> tag in ValidHtmlTags)
        {
            IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = (from n in allNodes.DescendantsAndSelf()
                                           where n.Name == tag.Key
                                           select n);

            if (nodes == null) continue;

            foreach (var n in nodes)
            {
                if (!n.HasAttributes) continue;

                // Get all the allowed attributes for this tag
                HtmlAttribute[] attr = n.Attributes.ToArray();
                foreach (HtmlAttribute a in attr)
                {
                    if (!tag.Value.Contains(a.Name))
                    {
                        a.Remove(); // Wasn't in the list
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // AntiXss
                        a.Value =
                            Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.UrlPathEncode(a.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return allNodes.InnerHtml;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a raw source and removes all HTML tags
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string StripHtml(string source)
    {
        source = SanitizeHtml(source);

        // No need to continue if we have no clean Html
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            return String.Empty;

        HtmlDocument html = GetHtml(source);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        // For each node, extract only the innerText
        foreach (HtmlNode node in html.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
            result.Append(node.InnerText);

        return result.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively delete nodes not in the whitelist
    /// </summary>
    private static void CleanNodes(HtmlNode node, string[] whitelist)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (!whitelist.Contains(node.Name))
            {
                node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                return; // We're done
            }
        }

        if (node.HasChildNodes)
            CleanChildren(node, whitelist);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply CleanNodes to each of the child nodes
    /// </summary>
    private static void CleanChildren(HtmlNode parent, string[] whitelist)
    {
        for (int i = parent.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            CleanNodes(parent.ChildNodes[i], whitelist);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper function that returns an HTML document from text
    /// </summary>
    private static HtmlDocument GetHtml(string source)
    {
        HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        html.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
        html.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        html.LoadHtml(source);

        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method are you using? Could you show your code? You cannot define whitelists. The library works with a built-in whitelist that you cannot change.

Comment: `var CleanHtml= Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(userinput);`. For example i need to not encode some html tag `<a>`,`<b>`,`<i>` etc

Comment: But you are calling `HtmlEncode` method! It's obvious that everything will be html encoded. That's what this method does. What you need us to use is the `var cleanHtml = Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(userinput);` method.

Comment: This works. Now i need to not remove `<a>` tag `href` attribute

Comment: I am afraid that the AntiXSS library doesn't allow this kind of customization. If you want to achieve that you might need to roll your custom sanitizer. For example you could use the HTML Agility Pack to parse the HTML and use a whitelist of tags and attributes (obviously this is now subject to your own validation, you should be careful with that because there's a reason why the href attribute is stripped out, this could be exploited for XSS attacks). Here's an example: http://eksith.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/whitelist-santize-htmlagilitypack/ I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: You save my time. But your code has little bug. When i use `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stack</a>` result is `<a href="http%3a/stackoverflow.com">stack</a>`. Then i find `a.Value =Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.UrlPathEncode(a.Value);` this row and replace to `a.Value =Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(a.Value);` .Now work successfully. Thank you.